# Python list insert function and datatype issue

Tags: python, list, numpy, insert, type-conversion

I am having an issue and I believe the cause is due to the nature of the insert function.
The documentation says that insert works like so:

```
list.insert(index, object)
```

The key point here is "object". In order to conduct an if statement that works on values, I converted my original list into an array. The data-type of this array was automatically calculated by python to be the following:

```
In [25]: MinorTrendTypeArr.dtype
Out[25]: dtype('int64')
```

However after inserting the required items in the list

```
MinorTrendType
```

The new array,

```
MinorTrendTypeArr2
```

As previously mentioned this must be because of the insert function's method of adding object items to the list. 
has data-type

```
In [25]: MinorTrendTypeArr2.dtype
Out[25]: dtype('object')
```

This is further evidenced by receiving the following error when trying to convert the the

```
MinorTrendType
```

variable into the new array.

```
In [27]: run triptrade.py
This is the length of MinorTrendType the first time = 12356
This is the length of MinorTrendType after adding plustwos elements = 13179
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/kane/tripkane_python/triptrade.py in <module>()
    579 
    580 MinorTrendArr2 = np.array(MinorTrend, dtype = np.int64)
--> 581 MinorTrendTypeArr2 = np.array(MinorTrendType, dtype = np.int64)
    582 
    583 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But the same problem does not arise in variable that did not have external values entered into it. I assume there is probably a way better way of doing things but am using my very limited knowledge at the moment to progress. Any help, suggestions of alternatives would be most welcome. Note: I can not enter all required values in the one loop as entering items changes the length of the list, unless as mentioned there is an easier work around.

Thanks in advance,

Kane

```
for n in range(0, len(MinorTrendType)):

    if MinorTrendTypeArr[n] == 2:
        plustwos.append(n)

pl = []
mi = []

PS1 = len(MinorTrendType)
print "This is the length of MinorTrendType the first time = %d" %PS1

for n in range(0, len(plustwos)):
    bbgun = plustwos[n] + len(plustwos[0:n])
    pl.append(bbgun)
    MinorTrendType.insert(pl[n], 22)
    MinorTrend.insert(pl[n], MinorTrend[pl[n]])


PS2 = len(MinorTrendType)
print "This is the length of MinorTrendType after adding plustwos elements = %d" %PS2

MinorTrendArr2 = np.array(MinorTrend, dtype = np.int64)
MinorTrendTypeArr2 = np.array(MinorTrendType, dtype = np.int64)
```

UPDATE/EDIT:

```
MinorTrendType
```

is a list of integers like so:
    MinorTrendType = [1,0,-1,1,0,-1,2,-1,1,-1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,-1,2,1,0,-2............]

```
MinorTrend
```

is a list of indices where
    MinorTrendType
values exist (these simply satisfy certain conditions). All I want to achieve is to insert markers at each occurence of 2 and -2 values within 
    MinorTrendType
and duplicate index values at the correpsonding sites within 
    MinorTrend
I have tried using 
    map(i, x)
    int(MinorTrendType[n])
within a loop and list and list comprehensions without success.I hope this makes things clearer. I don't care how it is done, just want to achieve it :)

Comment: I had quite a bit of difficulty following this.  A few basic questions.  1. " In order to conduct an if statement that works on values, I converted my original list into an array." - Was this to make the if statement more efficient?  Python's If statements handle any type of data just fine (including numeric values).  If that's all you need, you don't need numpy.  2. Why do you care about the data type for data?  Python is intended to be duck-typed (i.e., you don't care about the type, just the functionality).

Comment: Also, I should note that in Python, everything is an 'object' for all intents and purposes.  Any function that takes an 'object' can take ANY data type.

Comment: @Namey Thanks for your enquiries: 1) What I mean by that statement is when I converted the list to an array so that the if statement recognizes that any of the values in the array are numbers (in this case integers). When I conduct the if statement with a list it does not work. 2) I don't give a rats about the datatype, I just want the 2nd statement to work. I will give you more detail in an edit/update of the original problem. Hope this clarifies things a bit better. If it doesn't the update will, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hallelujah! The solution as lies in the fact that 
    MinorTrendArr2.dtype = 'object'
rather than
   'int64'
as I suspected. The solution lies in the following loop:

```
for n in range(0, len(plustwos)):
bbgun = plustwos[n] + len(plustwos[0:n])
pl.append(bbgun)
MinorTrendType.insert(pl[n], 22)
MinorTrend.insert(pl[n], MinorTrend[pl[n]])
```

This should read:

```
for n in range(0, len(plustwos)):
bbgun = plustwos[n] + len(plustwos[0:n])
pl.append(bbgun)
MinorTrendType.insert(pl[n], [22])
MinorTrend.insert(pl[n], MinorTrend[pl[n]])
```

The only difference being that the object being inserted into the list has [ ] around it. Then python assumes the array
    MinorTrendArr2
to be 
    'int64'
instead of object and allows for correct computation of the next if statement :)

Cheers